# There are need to validation check for event handler argument in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, arguments, eventhandler

Below is the sample code.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // case 1
   if (sender is ListBox)
   {
      ...
   }

   // case 2
   if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
   {
      if (e.AddedItems[0] is MyItemClass)
      {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Here, in case 1, we already know that the sender is a ListBox. But is it necessary to validation check like above sample code?

Likewise, in case 2, the item was selected in the listbox, and we already know what the item type is. But is it necessary to check the AddedItems.Count and type validation check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Theoretically you could have another child of listbox have it's own selection changed, and that event could bubble up to the listbox, which in turn will try to handle it. So, not likely, but considered proper if code reviewed.
2. Again, yes. Because selection changed means either Removed/Added and you can't know for sure what has changed. In case you do not care about the change itself, you could simply take the listbox instance from step 1 and check its SelectedItems, and use them instead.